# Remove an automatic correction from the dictionary?

Tags: iphone, spellcheck

At some point in the previous years, apple decided to include newspaper names in their dictionary. For Swiss French, this includes the words for morning and minutes, capitalised. So if write “munutes”, it gets corrected to Minutes and not minutes, which is particularly annoying. Is it possible to remove this word from the spellchecking?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a workaround for this.

Navigate to Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Text Replacement

You can now add "munutes" as the phrase and shortcut.

This will ensure your spell check won't autocorrect "munutes" from now on.

I have had to do this for my actual name as well as some of my friends names as autocorrect isn't a fan of Irish names.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there are infinitely many ways I can fat finger "minutes". And it doesn't prevent it from capitalising properly spelled "minutes" and "morning".

Comment: Well I tried to help...

Comment: Yes, and thank you. But while it may be helpful in some cases - like yours - it isn't a solution in mine.